# How do I return a list created inside a scheme function?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm trying to look up atoms of a list passed to the translate function translate the atom to the appropriate number, and output a new list. I'm getting the following error:

```
outlist: unbound identifier in module in: outlist
```

Here is my code:

```
#lang racket
(define chinese '(ling yi er san si wu liu qi ba jiu shi))
(define english '(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten))

(define (translate alist)
  (cond
     ((eq? "zero" (car alist) cons ('(0)) outlist)
  )
 (translate (cdr alist))))

(define list '(zero))
(translate list)
```

What I'm looking for is to pass translate a list that contains "one two three" etc and get a list from translate with "1 2 3" contained in it..

I've also tried adding

```
 (define outlist '())
```

inside the translate function and the following error is thrown:

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: '(0)
arguments...: [none]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Really what I should be doing is looking up the string of the user generated list in english and chinese, then doing the translation, so if you can elaborate on how to do this, that would help as well.

Comment: [Here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is an excellent, and free, book. [This](http://www.htdp.org) is also good. And free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a parameter or variable called `outlist`, you're supposed to *build* the output list as you go - and remember to write a correct base case for the recursion.

Also, there are multiple syntax errors with your code, make sure that you *understand* how to call a function in Scheme. You should try something like this:

```
(define (translate alist)
  (cond
    ((null? alist) '())
    ((eq? 'zero (car alist))
     (cons 0 (translate (cdr alist))))
    ((eq? 'one (car alist))
     (cons 1 (translate (cdr alist))))
    ... and so on ...))
```

It works as expected:

```
(translate '(zero one))
=> '(0 1)
```